# extract highest accuracy from tensorflow mobile demo image classifier

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have pre-trained my model of fruit images using this tutorial for training CNN and deployed in my android device.I have created my own activity with a fab button to launch the classifier.How do i extract the highest accuracy shown as soon as i press the back button and then show on a textview
[Tensorflow for poets link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#0)
Here's what i have tried

My code is given below

**Mainactivity.java**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 1) {
     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         String strEditText = data.getStringExtra("editTextValue");
     }     
}

        floatingActionButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });
```

This is the method from class with fragment that returns the text i want to show on my mainactivity.

```
private void showToast(final String text) {
final Activity activity = getActivity();
if (activity != null) {
  activity.runOnUiThread(
      new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          textView.setText(text);
        }
      });
}
```

The activity that launches the fragment

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    if (null == savedInstanceState) {
      getFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.container, Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance())
          .commit();
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Please include the code that runs the model and gives the classification output.

Comment: This is an extremely vague question, can you please expand on it, "How do i extract the highest accuracy shown as soon as i press the back button"

Comment: @DavidParks What i want is to send the accuracy from the method ShowToast  to my mainactivity using intent when i press the back button on the navbar

Comment: @dazza5000 if you want the complete code you can get it from tensorflow repository.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/app